# Prev & Next Buttons Loop Through Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, slider, carousel

I am trying to get the following to loop through the projects (Fade in / Fade Out). But as of now, when you click on the Prev & Next buttons it is only loading the array names and not the content.

I have setup a JS Fiddle file here. http://jsfiddle.net/leemnelson_/Ur7SW/29/

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle without using id's and using classes instead.. Also trimmed out the extra wrappers.. Check it in my post ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur7SW/33/

You're setting the `.html()` to the string value in the array. You need to use jQuery to the ***element*** with that id.

So instead of:

```
$('.innerContent').html(webProjects);
```

Use:

```
$('.innerContent').html($("#"+ webProjects[c]));
```

It looks like there's still something going on with your previous button...I'll take a look at that now.

---

There were other problems as well. Problem with the previous button, repeated `id` attributes, reusing the same element, etc. I have fixed all of them in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur7SW/49/

Comment: @user1695138: There were some other problems as well. Take a look at my edited post and the new fiddle.

Comment: Wow. THANK YOU. You have no idea how much this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First things first .. ID should be **unique** .. And you are having so many elements with the same ID.

Try replacing the same with class names which makes your code cleaner.

Also why do you want to overload your page by having the same Div over and over again when you can simply Have a single div for the navigation..

And the projects in separate div ..

**UPDATE CODE**

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Ur7SW/36/)

I have made the required modifications for it to work with a Single Div wrapper that loads the projects

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the entire array and placing it as HTML. Instead load the array element as shown below:

```
$('.innerContent .projectInfo').html(webProjects[c]);
```

And you are placing the array value as HTML which is replacing the buttons with the array. Try placing the array value in the separate div which does not include buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the help monhanrajt! I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

chk the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ur7SW/32/

the text should go inside the `p` element

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help Sandeep! I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.